# How do you upload/edit files on your web development server?

Tags: linux, webserver

For a long time now I have been using a local XAMPP installation on my OS X machine for all my web development. Because updating/maintaing XAMPP is such a pain, I set up an Ubuntu server for my web development.

I would like to know what you think is the best/easiest way to connect to your main development server to edit the files. What protocol do you use (smb, webdav, fdp, ldap, etc.)? Also, do you leave the files on your machine and let the server read the files form your hard drive (e.g. smb via a smb) or do you leave the files on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with SMB as your means of file transfer. How you do this is up to you. It depends on how often your files are accessed, how often they are updated, etc. If you plan on updating the files often (i.e. if you are in a rapid dev phase) then you can link them like you talked about. If the updating is infrequent and the amount of requests are high, upload them to the server. This will decrease the amount of stress on your LAN as the files are requested; in the other method the route would have been modem -- SMB server -- SMB share -- SMB server -- modem, wheras this way it is modem -- SMB server -- modem.

Comment: I update the files very often, and I'm more or less the only one updating those files. So in this scenario you would suggest leaving the files on my hard drive and the server accessing them via smb?

Comment: Yeah, in that case that is the best scenario.

Comment: I'd really like to know: What are you using for your day-to-day web development?

Comment: @wow The majority of my work is backend. It is almost all application based. I'll spend hours and hours working on one PHP script before I test it, and I don't host any of my own servers. I have dedicated offsite testing servers where FTP works perfectly fine. Speed isn't a priority as I do max 10 uploads a day.

Comment: Thanks! Always interesting to see which setup other people use.

Answer (score 1):

I use an Ubuntu Virtual Machine running the web server, git and vim.  So I backup everything my Vim configuration and server config.  For me is the fastest way to recover from a crash in example.

Also, you can use `vim` through `ssh` by

```
vim scp://myuser@server.com//home/myuser/file
```

A simpler example is to view source with an editor syntax, indent

```
vim http://domain.com
```

You can save ssh credentials too

Comment: Sounds interesting. Do you run git on your local machine an push the changes to your development server or do you run git on your server and pull the changes form you local machine?

Comment: Usually I push a mirror to a dedicated server just for backup, my actual development server is the same local VM. On the other hand, hackers love SMB and FTP, avoid them as much as possible and only use secured channels such as ssh, sftp, scp.

Comment: I also would only use SMB or FTP over a VPN connection. But using VIM via SSH is a great idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [Aptana](http://aptana.com) (an Eclipse derivative) over ssh/sftp to edit the files directly on my server.

If you need to transfer files I suggest using something like [FileZilla](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://filezilla-project.org/&rct=j&q=filezilla&ei=7mn6TefYCoT00gHQts3OAw&usg=AFQjCNFi0DpQ1I5V_nCUkxMoqvM1kA5XnA&sig2=jbmXbjOCKHALD7X-uLteVA&cad=rja) which will let you connect over ftp or ssh/sftp.

Comment: Do you also transfere your assets via Aptana (images, etc.)? I'm currently currently considering switching to Vim or Eclipse as my main editor ([see my stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363895/should-i-switch-form-my-current-editor-to-vim-or-an-ide-for-php-js-css-html)), Aptana looks very interesting. I think it's the Eclips I've been looking for. You may want to post your recommendation there!

Comment: Well Aptana can do anything Eclipse can do, plus it has additional features for working with HTML/JS/CSS/etc. And no, I don't 'transfer' assets via Aptana. I run Linux as my OS which has tools to open up sftp as a folder in my system. For those who don't run linux I suggest transfers using FileZilla like I put in my post. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used to map a SMB share of my LAMP server and edit the PHP files directly with Dreamweaver. Worked really well.

Lol, i'm the first one in the [testimonial here](http://news.samba.org/users/everyday_samba/index.html). Oh memories.